# Observational Cosmology, light polarisation

Tags: cosmology

Can anyone explain the purpose of measuring light polarisation, as carried out by the upcoming planck satellite?

Comment: [This](http://astro.berkeley.edu/~mwhite/polar/) website explains it quite well. Incidentally, it isn't "upcoming", it was launched in 2009. :)

Answer (score 1):

Polarized light carries information about the geometrical and optical properties of the source or medium

Many a times in observational astronomy, we need information on the interstellar/intergalactic medium and its scattering properties. That is observed by how it affects the polarization of light from a source behind it.
That was one example. Here's a link:

http://physics.bu.edu/py106/notes/Polarization.html

The above link explains some reasons which might cause polarization of light. And these are employed to study the properties of source and medium.

On a personal note, though, there are no limitations. There might be other reasons which polarize light, yet to be undiscovered. It's a delicate property.

Comment: And of course, there's just the fact that you want to gather all of the information available to you!